# Changing USER_PASS credentials text

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a community connector, and I want to customize or append to the message that is shown before the input form.  Currently it says:

"[App name] requires your [App name] username and password in order to access your data. Do not enter your Google account information."

I would like it to say:

"[App name] requires your [App name] username and password in order to access your data. Do not enter your Google account information.  **Please enter your [App name] API access_key/secret_key for the username/password fields.**"

Is there any way to customize the text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is at the moment. A possible work around could be to have that information within the "description" field in the manifest file?